# Bash finding procces trouble

Tags: bash, shell-script

I just wanted to make a script is spotifyd running or not or error.

My Plan is simple:

```
Check is spotifyd running (y/n)
if yes
say "It's running"
if no
try to run

did it work (y/n)
if yes
say It started
if no
say it gave an error
```

(More understandable version: If spotifyd gives an error, don't start the daemon. So if it doesn't run, we will try to run. If still doesn't run, say error)

Here's my code (i am noob, so your eyes might bleed)

```
date=$(date "+%d.%m.%Y %H.%M")

if [ "spotifyd" == $(ps aux | grep spotifyd | grep "0.1" | awk '{print $11}') ]; then
    echo "[$date] Procces is allready running"
    exit
elif [ "" == $(ps aux | grep spotifyd | grep "0.1" | awk '{print $11}') ]; then 
    spotifyd 
    exit
elif [ "spotifyd" == $(ps aux | grep spotifyd | grep "0.1" | awk '{print $11}') ]; then 
    echo "Procces has started"
    exit
elif [ "err" == $(ps aux | grep spotifyd | grep "0.1" | awk '{print $11}' || echo "err") ]; then
    echo "[$date] Procces couldn't start. Check the procces' manual" 
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Does your system provide the `pgrep` command? More generally, daemons are typically started and managed by an init process such as systemd (in which case you may be able to use something like `systemd is-active` to poll the status)

Comment: i can  add spotifyd as a systemd daemon but it works wacky.

Comment: @LinuxAndBash could you elaborate how `spotifyd` as `systemd`-service does not work for you? It could have a `restart=on-failure` line.

Comment: That is not from me. It is known bug.

Comment: Efficient way if the process is running ` if [[ $(ps -C spotifyed -o pid=) ]]`   `ps -C spotifyed -o pid=` returns PID of spotifyed process.` [[ $(ps -C spotifyed -o pid=) ]]` returns true if not empty.

Comment: Thanks i made it!